React not picking up @babel/preset-react or @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx
I'm trying to use react-native-subtitles in a React project. I've added @babel/preset-react and @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx to my .babelrc file, but I still get the error that 'Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled'. I can't figure out why I'm still getting the error. For references, here's my .babelrc
{
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "modules": false
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"
    ]
}

Looking at other similar errors online, adding to the .babelrc fixed the issue for most people. I also tried creating a babel.config.js file instead, to no avail.

Does this work for you?
import * as babel from '@babel/core';

const code = `const element = <div>Hello JSX!</div>;`;
const options = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx']
};

try {
  const result = babel.transform(code, options);
  if (result !== null) {
    console.log('JSX Transpilation successful:', result.code);
  } else {
    console.error('Transpilation returned null, possibly due to configuration issues.');
  }
} catch (error: any) {
  console.error('Error during JSX transpilation:', error.message);
}


No, including that import causes several of these errors:
ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js 10:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\laure\movewsarah\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:

add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
install 'path-browserify'

